# for each regex match in bash

Tags: bash, regular-expression

I am looking for something like this...

Given this file (lets call it "foo.log"):

```
START_OF_ENTRY
line2
END_OF_ENTRY
START_OF_ENTRY
no match
END_OF_ENTRY
START_OF_ENTRY
line2
END_OF_ENTRY
```

Executing the following command:

```
pcregrep -M -o '(?m)^START_OF_ENTRY\nline2\nEND_OF_ENTRY$' foo.log | for match in STDIN; do echo "match: $match"; done
```

would produce

```
match: START_OF_ENTRY
line2
END_OF_ENTRY
match: START_OF_ENTRY
line2
END_OF_ENTRY
```

Is this possible in bash?

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "in bash"? are you looking for a solution using only shell features?

Comment: yes - I'm curious as to if it's possible only with the shell - preferably with bash only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using bash regular expression matching *with the proviso that there does not appear to be a multiline equivalent of the `^` and `$` anchors in bash*:

```
x=$(<foo.log)

printf -v re 'START_OF_ENTRY\nline2\nEND_OF_ENTRY'

while [[ $x =~ $re ]]; do 
  printf 'match: %s\n' "${BASH_REMATCH[0]}"; x=${x#*${BASH_REMATCH[0]}};
done
match: START_OF_ENTRY
line2
END_OF_ENTRY
match: START_OF_ENTRY
line2
END_OF_ENTRY
```

With Perl, in which you can use the `m` modifier to make `^` and `$` meaningful in a multiline context:

```
perl -0777 -nE 'while ($_ =~ /^(START_OF_ENTRY\nline2\nEND_OF_ENTRY)$/mg) {say "match: $1"}' foo.log
```

Comment: Capturing the whole file in memory will use more memory. That could be an issue with big files. Also, processing text in the shell is usually a bad idea as the shell is quite slow on such tasks.